# Is there any way to not set updated_at column on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to not set the updated_at column when i using `update()`, is there any way to make it possible? thank you

Comment: Please, add an **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** to show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of options to the second parameter of the update method, which then tells laravel to not update the timestamps like so:

```
->update(['name' => 'foo'], ['timestamps' => false]);
```

Comment: This option is removed since Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

Check your table structure, I think `updated_at` is having `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, which means this column will automatically get its value when a new value added or some changes is done on a row. So remove that `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and try again.

To check table definition try `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`.